Entity Framework Core 8: IQueryable "Include" method not found
This question is pretty much a duplicate of this one except that answer is 8 years old and not working for me. Also this one, this one, and this one.
Every answer I can find to this question just says to add using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore; (and the first answer linked also specifies using System.Linq;.) I have installed Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 8.0.10 as well as Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 8.0.10 through nuget, and have added both using statements.
To ensure there wasn't any other using conflicting, I even tried removing all using statements other than the 2 specified, and Include was still not found. I also tried some other random ones, like Microsoft.Data.Sql or Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.
I have also tried reinstalling both packages through nuget, cleaning/rebuilding the solution, and restarting Visual Studio multiple times.
Obviously I am also using .NET Core 8.

'IQueryable' does not contain a definition for 'Include' and no accessible extension method 'Include' accepting a first argument of type 'IQueryable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Code:
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Linq;

IQueryable queryable = GetQueryableByTableName("table1");
queryable.Include("table2");


please provide the code snippet to see what you are trying to achieve

queryable = queryable.Include(table);

Probably packages are not installed. Maybe you are trying to use EF Core 8 with .NET Framework?

It's hard to figure out what the problem is based on a description of code. Please [edit] your post with a [mre]. For example this works just fine for me https://dotnetfiddle.net/oMZlwt

Which table? You should specify navigation property queryable = queryable.Include(x => x.Customer);

No, I am on .NET Core 8 and using EF Core 8:

Exe
net8.0
enable
enable



is your project .net core or framework? And what version is it?

Please [edit] your post with additional information. Info in comments are hard to read and easy to delete.

Fine, edited to include the obvious info

It's not obvious, otherwise we wouldn't be asking all these clarification questions. What does GetQueryableByTableName do? Really, please read through [mre].

It returns an IQueryable. It doesn't really matter what it does specifically, since the problem is that IQueryable does not have the "Include" method when it should given the using statement.

As I showed with my prior dotnet fiddler link, I can't reproduce what you're seeing. It works just fine for me. https://i.sstatic.net/gwEh5vRI.png

Pro tip for debugging inaccessible extension methods in the future: try calling them with a regular static method call (EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.Include(query)) and see what error message you get.

In EF Core 8, there are no non-generic overloads of the Include method. So you'll need to have your IQueryable be a generically-typed IQueryable<> of some kind. If you don't know the type, it's possible you can leverage dynamic typing to determine and invoke the right generic version of the method at run-time:
IQueryable queryable = GetQueryableByTableName("table1");
queryable = EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.Include((dynamic)queryable, "table2");

